# Fastest way to convert an ext4 formatted disk to LVM with ext4 on it?

Tags: ext4, lvm

I'm currently doing `cp -aR` to copy data from my (99% full) 1TB ext4 formatted disk to a new LVM-with-ext4-on-it disk. It's taking forever.

Is there any way to attempt to "convert" the disk in place? I'm on EC2 so backing up takes minutes.

Or alternatively, is there any way that might be faster than `cp` to directly copy the ext4 filesystem onto the LVM disk?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wrote [blocks](https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme) (née lvmify) which does this conversion in-place. It works by shrinking the filesystem a bit, moving the start of the filesystem to the end of the partition, and copying an LVM superblock (preconfigured with the right PV/LV/VG) in its place.

Comment: this sounds really interesting! I am thinking on backuping my 500GB to the other partition (that is already lvm) just to give it a try!

Comment: I used it successfully to convert my 2 ext4 paritions totalling 120GB, the whole process took about 2 minutes and the result is pretty solid. Thanks for writing blocks!

Comment: One caveat should be mentioned regarding `blocks`: it can convert regular volume to the LVM one, but if this volume was bootable, the great chance it will not boot after the procedure, if you will not do some GRUB reinstallation procedures manually. Should be mentioned in man or something, I believe.

Comment: @Gabriel, will this work on live fs? I mean do I need to unmount the FS, and then it does it in-place, or will it even work on a r/w mounted root FS?

Comment: @AmrMostafa: "Pretty" solid? I have this thing about my file systems, I need them to be *rock* solid... :-)

Comment: Ubuntu Trusty+ users will find it hard to install the required python 3.3.. only 3.4 is available and blocks hasn't been updated since Dec 2014 :/

Comment: That sounded very promising, but unfortunately the project seems abandoned, and according to the issues tracker there are problems with current distributions which have moved to Python 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: Despite the fact that it was updated 5 ears ago, it steel working. Confirmed on NVMe SSD, GPT partition scheme. Note: better use Python 3.6.

Comment: I'm using it with Python 3.8 with no problems. By the way, I created an [archlinux aur package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python-g2p-blocks-git/), in case anyone on arch wants to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Manual lvmify:

1. Shrink filesystem by 8 MiB (if the length is a multiple of 4 MiB shrinking by 4 MiB is enough; if not sure shrink a bit more and expand filesystem to maximum size after step 7) or increase the size of the partition to a multiple of 4 MiB and having 1 free 4 MiB block at the end.
2. Copy the first 4 MiB to the location of the last 4 MiB aligned block, e.g. with a 17 MiB disk that's at 12 MiB (toy example for simplicity, see illustration below).
3. Create PV with `--dataalignment 4M`
4. Create VG
5. Create LV with `--extents 1`, `-Zn` and PV specification `/dev/sdX:1234` where `sdX` is your disk (add the partition number if used) and `1234` the last extent number, i.e. number of available extents - 1. In the example, we have 3 extents (4 MiB header, 12 MiB usable space, 1 MiB trailing space) and the index of the last extent is 2.
6. Grow LV (`lvextend`) to full size, e.g. with `-l+100%FREE`
7. Check plausibility of the data in the new LV. Steps 5+6 can be repeated with corrected numbers after removing the LV. (Assuming no journal replay damaged the data.)

Illustration (toy example with 17 MiB disk):

```
Meta| PV usable | trailing data
+---+---+---+---+-+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | |
+---+---+---+---+-+
  |           ^
   \----------/ copy

Shrinking filesystem to 3 extents (12 MiB).
LV extents: 0 (was 3), 1, 2
```

Ideas for testing this approach before touching important data:

- Create a sparse file and a loop device (or use a VM), fill the first and last 20 MiB or so with random data (or sequential block numbers), get the md5sum of the relevant data (excluding the area we overwrite in step 2 and the trailing data), follow steps, check that md5sum of LV contents matches earlier md5sum
- Create a device snapshot (100 MiB backing storage should be plenty, this can be on a tmpfs), e.g. following https://gist.github.com/jowagner/b36024636140ddf453c12eaf6e590b5d, and work on the writeable snapshot for testing.

If you are not 100% sure like me whether `dd seek=` does the right thing for step 2 here a few lines of Python code that I used:

```python
dev_name = 'dev/sdX'
dev_size = 24000272007168  # put size in bytes here
pe_size = 4096 * 1024
n_extents = dev_size // pe_size
f = open(dev_name, 'r+b')
f.seek(0)
block = f.read(pe_size)
assert len(block) == pe_size
f.seek(pe_size*(n_extents-1))
f.write(block)
f.close()
```

Comment: With an additional PV it can be done without shrinking the filesystem, see my answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/241987/convert-full-hard-drive-to-lvm-without-external-storage/

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about how to convert the disk live, but I think rsync will be a better and safer way to copy your data over. It'll allow you to resume and keep the data intact in the event the transfer stops.

I did find a similar process completed by someone adding an external drive to their local system as an LVM. There's not a whole lot of information, but I think it will be enough to get your started:

> "So today I discovered the awesome that is LVM. Installing Debian, I selected "LVM - Use entire disk". But the main drive was a slow and small 5200rpm laptop drive. Today I inserted my spare 1.5TB drive and booted up. Wanted the system on this bigger faster drive instead.
>
> LVM approach: add /dev/sdc to the volume group, then run "pvmove /dev/sda". This moves all data from sda to other drives (only sdc available). No need to reboot, no need to unmount. While I'm writing this, the data is being moved.
>
> Later, do "vgreduce megatron /dev/sda" to remove the slow drive from the volume group and voila. Data moved. (megatron is the name of the volume group and of my computer).
> This might be old news to many but I just thought this was really cool :)"

Granted this was done locally, but I think with additional research, you maybe be able to accomlpish this.

[source](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/123399/til_how_to_move_my_entire_system_to_a_second/)

Answer (score 1):

No method exists to do such an LVM conversion "on the fly."

LVM actually resides under your filesystem to expand it across multiple physical devices, or stripe or mirror it, etc. The final step in creating a logical volume is to lay a file system on top of it. [Here are examples](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/index.html#LVM_examples) from RHEL6.

What you will need to do is back up or archive the data on that device, then destroy existing filesystem, create a logical volume, and re-lay a filesystem on top. If this is a root filesystem on a linux OS, consider doing a reinstallation. It may be faster.

For faster copies, I'm fond of `dd`, but I don't use it often. Making a mistake with `dd` is dangerous. One thing you can try is `tar czv <source fs> | (cd <destination fs>; tar x)` which will transfer a compressed tar file on the fly.

Good luck!

Comment: Using _compression_ in the tar operation makes no sense at all. The only place the data will be compressed is in-**memory** as it's piped; it's then immediately uncompressed again before it gets written to disk. Only now, the operation generates multiple times as much CPU load because it's both compressing and uncompressing, uselessly, on the fly.
Also, for any operation like this involving entire filesystems, you're going to want at _least_ `tar cSf - | tar xvpf -` to handle sparse files & permissions. Possibly `--selinux` too (if the destination volume will subsequently replace the source).

Comment: That's a good point if your source and destination devices are on the same host or if you don't have CPU cycles to spare. Those are points to consider case by case. I do like the "S" and "p" switches and the "--selinux" argument.

Comment: Mmm, well, if anyone's cloning a filesystem by piping an on-the-fly tar operation over a network link, then (a) they're a braver soul than I, but (b) you might NOT want `-p` unless the hosts share usernames/UIDs (though the manpage reminds me that `-p` is the default for GNU tar when run as root), and `--selinux` is fraught with even more peril — probably better to just do a `restorecon -Rv` (or `-Rp`) over the whole thing once it's mounted in the correct (final) location.

Comment: dd is the proper tool for this operation since you're copying a partition.  dd will make an exact copy on the new partition, then you change the fstab to load from the new partition instead of the old.  Once you're done moving all the partitions off the old drive, you can destroy the filesystem and add the drive to the LVM physical disks group, and then use the space to expand the partitions however you wish.

Comment: "No method exists" is plain wrong, see accepted answer and my "manual lvmify" answer.